# How to stream a file in post/put request with error handling?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, node-streams

#### This is not a question about "what is the best way to refactor the following code". it's about "how can I refactor the following code to have any control over both of the exceptions".

---

I have the following code which stream a file in a PUT request.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import got from 'got' // it doesn't really matters if it's `axious` or `got`

async function sendFile(addressToSend: string, filePath: string) {
      const body = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      body.on('error', () => {
        console.log('we cached the error in block-1')
      })
      try {
        const result = await client.put(addressToSend, {
          body,
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('we cached the error in block-2')
      }
}
```

---

I'm trying to refactor this code in such a way that will give me the opportunity to catch all the errors from in a single place.

The above solution does not give me a way to test a failure of the `stream`. for example, if I pass a file that does not exist, the function will print both `we cached the error in block-1` and `we cached the error in block-2` but i don't have a way to re-throw that first error or use it in the tests in anyway.

---

Note:

I'm not sure if the best way to solve it is to do this:

Because when I pass a filePath that does not exist, the `rej` function will be called twice which is very bad practice.

```js
function sendFile(addressToSend: string, filePath: string) {
  return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    const body = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    body.on('error', () => {
      console.log('we cached the error in block-1')
      rej('1')
    })
    try {
      const result = await client.put(addressToSend, {
        body,
      })
      res()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('we cached the error in block-2')
      rej('2')
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like it that much but this is the best I could think of:

```js
function streamFilePut(client: Got, url: string, filePath: string) {
  const body = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  const streamErrorPromise = new Promise((_, rej) => body.on('error', rej))

  const resultPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    return client
      .put(url, {
        body,
      })
      .then(res, rej)
  })

  return Promise.race([streamErrorPromise, resultPromise])
}
```